# Smack : Is it possible to get the message composed by the user as he writes it in a chat?

Tags: spring, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, smack

We have a chat application which is using Smack, XMPP, ejabberd. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve something like below:

1. A chat is open between 2 users.
2. User1 is typing some message.
3. User2 is able to see the message typed by User1 as he types it.

I have done a bit of research but couldn't find anything related.

Please let me know how to achieve this use case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You can send the text as user types but each piece will go as independent message. If you want that one you might want to have your own way to do so. XMPP have no way to do so!

Answer (score 0):

With Smack it is easy, whenever the user changes the text you send a typing stanza to the other person using the `ChatStateExtension`:

```
 private void sendTypingStatus(final String toJid) {
     //you must have a valid xmpp connection of course
     if (null == mConnection)
        return;

    try {
        Message message = new Message(JidCreate.from(toJid));
        message.addExtension(new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.composing));

        message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
        mConnection.sendStanza(message);

    } catch (InterruptedException | SmackException.NotConnectedException | XmppStringprepException ex) {
        Log.w(TAG, "sendTypingStatus error", ex);
    }
}
```

The other person should be prepared to receive the stanza and use it correctly. The best option is to use `ChatStatesStanzaListener` for that:

```
public class ChatStatesStanzaListener implements StanzaListener {

private static final String TAG = ChatStatesStanzaListener.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
    Message message = (Message) packet;
    if (message.hasExtension(ChatStateExtension.NAMESPACE)) {
        ChatStateExtension chatStateExtension = (ChatStateExtension) message.getExtension(ChatStateExtension.NAMESPACE);
        ChatState chatState = chatStateExtension.getChatState();
        String fromJid = message.getFrom().asBareJid().toString();

        if (message.getType().equals(Message.Type.chat)) {
            Log.v(TAG, "got chat state " + fromJid + " " + message.getType() + " " + chatState);
 //you got youe information here, call a callback or broadcast an event, whatever

        } else if (message.getType().equals(Message.Type.groupchat)) {
            //out of your question
        }
    }
}
```

}

Don't forget to add the stanza listener to your xmpp connection once it's established:
1. Set the stanza filter:

```
 // set up a stanzalistener and filter chatstates messages only
        StanzaFilter chatStatesStanzaFilter = stanza -> {
            // filter for chatstates message only
            return stanza.hasExtension(ChatStateExtension.NAMESPACE);
        };
```

2. Use it once you initialize the xmpp connection:

   ```
   mConnection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new ChatStatesStanzaListener(), chatStatesStanzaFilter);
   ```

I hope it helps :)